# PHP PDO query return null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I have an issue while using PDO, I am new to this. The query return null array if I using the first method:

```
try {
    $r = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id` = :id AND `key` = :key LIMIT 1";
    $r_do = $db->prepare($r);
    $r_do->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $r_do->bindParam(':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $r_do->execute();
    $f2 = $r_do->fetch();
} catch(PDOException $r) {
  $log->logError($r." - ".basename(__FILE__));
}
```

where $id is integer and $key is an ecrypted string e.g iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC+m8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0=

The value come from an URL

```
signin.php?id=10&key=iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC+m8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0=
```

If i directly replace the prepared statement with it value, the query will return the result.

```
$r = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `id` = '10' AND `key` = 'iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC+m8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0=' LIMIT 1";
```

Any idea? For your info I am using Webmatrix as IDE with PHP on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Could you `var_dump($key)`? With `+` and `=` in the text, it might be being converted for you somewhere along the way.

Comment: return string(44) "iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC m8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0="
When I use 
die(var_export($db->errorinfo(), TRUE)); 
it return 
array ( 0 => '00000', 1 => NULL, 2 => NULL, )

Comment: Yeah, it's getting editted - see that space in the middle, where your `+` was? You need to run the code through `urlencode()` on the page where you're generating the link; and `urldecode()` on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thanks @andrewsi !! I've spent the whole day figuring out this. You're my savior.

Comment: You're welcome - sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

```
signin.php?id=10&key=iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC+m8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0=
```

The problem is this. When the value of `key` is read, that `+` is being interpreted as a space.

To get around that, on the page that generates the link, you need to call `urlencode()` - that will encode the characters properly, and should give you something like:

```
signin.php?id=10&key=iGkGNI1NEzCZ6k9g9xC%2Bm8hNm22G3DXsNoEqdwNkTc0=
```

In *this* page, you can get the correct value of `id` by running it through `urldecode()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using

```
PDO::PARAM_INT
```

Instead of

```
PDO::PARAM_STR
```

For your ID, since it's an Int.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @andrewsi for the thought. Send the encrypted string with urlencode() then add urldecode() to retrieve the string.

Note: However, `+` symbol still not working. I've made few more data with `+` and the result still null eventhough encode/decode is working.